# Why this Loop seems to process only one image?

Tags: python, loops

Could someone help to understand why this code is not processing ALL the images? or how to make sure that it processed all the images? Please see what happened when I printed out features and labels:

```
def extract_features(list_images):
     nb_features = 2048
     features = np.empty((len(list_images),nb_features))
     labels = []
     create_graph()
     with tf.Session() as sess:
         next_to_last_tensor = `sess.graph.get_tensor_by_name('pool_3:0')`

         for ind, image in enumerate(list_images):
             if (ind%100 == 0):
                print('Processing %s...' % (image))
                if not gfile.Exists(image):
                      tf.logging.fatal('File does not exist %s', image)
             image_data = gfile.FastGFile(image, 'rb').read()
             predictions = sess.run(next_to_last_tensor,
             {'DecodeJpeg/contents:0': image_data})
             features[ind,:] = np.squeeze(predictions)
             labels.append(re.split('_\d+',image.split('/')[1])[0])
         return features, labels
```

As you see below In [11]: "Processing images/Young-Bengal-tiger.jpg..." it seems that the LOOP only proccesed ONE image.

```
In [11]: features,labels = extract_features(list_images)
```

**Processing images/Young-Bengal-tiger.jpg..**.
W tensorflow/core/framework/op_def_util.cc:332] Op BatchNormWithGlobalNormalization is deprecated. It will cease to work in GraphDef version 9. Use tf.nn.batch_normalization().

I'm supposed to see something like:

```
Processing images/baby_shoe_0.jpg...
Processing images/basketball_hoop_0.jpg...
Processing images/bath_spa_0.jpg...
Processing images/binocular_0.jpg...
Processing images/birdcage_0.jpg...
Processing images/birdhouse_0.jpg...
Processing images/boot_0.jpg...
Processing images/cabinet_0.jpg...
Processing images/calculator_0.jpg...
...etc...
```

Please see image containing:

1. print (features)
2. print (labels)

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've set it to only print 'Processing .....' every 100 images it processes.

Remove the line `if (ind%100 == 0):` and it should show what you're after assuming the rest of the code works.

Doing the `if not i % number` thing works really well if there's thousands or millions of records, but for a handful of images there shouldn't be much need.

```
def extract_features(list_images):
     nb_features = 2048
     features = np.empty((len(list_images),nb_features))
     labels = []
     create_graph()
     with tf.Session() as sess:
         next_to_last_tensor = `sess.graph.get_tensor_by_name('pool_3:0')`

         for ind, image in enumerate(list_images):
             print('Processing %s...' % (image))
             if not gfile.Exists(image):
                 tf.logging.fatal('File does not exist %s', image)
             image_data = gfile.FastGFile(image, 'rb').read()
             predictions = sess.run(next_to_last_tensor,
             {'DecodeJpeg/contents:0': image_data})
             features[ind,:] = np.squeeze(predictions)
             labels.append(re.split('_\d+',image.split('/')[1])[0])
         return features, labels
```